# Is there any way to see every value of the variable as it changes in the watch window?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, watch

I basically just want to see a history of the variable as it changes during each Continue.

Can it be done? Or should I just log it to a file?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your variable a property? if so you can write out to the immediate window in the `set`

Comment: @Brad It is. I don't know why I hadn't thought of that. That should do just fine. If you submit the answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your variable a property? If so you can write out to the immediate window in the `set`

Say you have a class such as

```
class MyClass
{
    private int myVariable;

    public int MyVariable
    {
        get
        {
            return this.myVariable;
        }
        set
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(value.ToString());
            this.myVariable = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could call code like this

```
    MyClass mc = new MyClass();
    mc.MyVariable = 1;
    mc.MyVariable = 2;
```

And the output would be

```
1
2
```

The default setting in Visual Studio is for `Debug.Print()` to write to the `Output Window`. If you want it to go to the `Immediate Window` instead go

> Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Redirect all Output Window text to Immediate Window

Comment: @Winky I added an example of how you could use this concept